# Помощь с версткой

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в данном коде сделать, чтобы тест выпадал плавно вправо

```css
.content {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top; /* по умолчанию baseline */
      background: #ccc;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    
    .hide {
      display: none;
      background: #000;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .content:hover .hide {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="content">
      hover
      <p class="hide">
        Text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      hover
      <p class="hide">
        Text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      hover
      <p class="hide">
        Text
      </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: надо сначало спозиционировать его с права а потом уже скрыть его и показать по hover

Comment: Я ещё начинающий, не могу разобраться... Не подскажете?

Comment: для родителя : relative для потомка absolute и вообще https://webref.ru/css/position

Answer (score 6):

```css
    .content {
          display: inline-block;
          vertical-align: top; /* по умолчанию baseline */
          background: #ccc;
          padding: 5px;
          position: relative;
        }
        .hide {
          background: #000;
          color: #fff;
          text-align: center;
          position: absolute;
          top: -17px;
          right: -55px;
          z-index: 2;
          width: 0px;
          height: 30px; 
          overflow: hidden;
        }
        .content:hover .hide {
          width: 50px;
          transition: width 0.1s;
        }
```

```html
 <div class="content">
      hover
      <p class="hide">
        Text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      hover
      <p class="hide">
        Text
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      hover
      <p class="hide">
        Text
      </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Задание ваше звучит непонятно, что значит выпадал. В любом случае, вот мой вариант:

```css
.content {
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.hide {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: opacity 0.9s;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.content:hover .hide {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  hover
  <p class="hide">
    Text
  </p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  hover
  <p class="hide">
    Text
  </p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  hover
  <p class="hide">
    Text
  </p>
</div>
```

Скорее всего придётся вам дорабатывать код под себя, также необходимо проверить кроссбраузерность.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.content {
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

.hide {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.content:hover .hide {
  transform: translateX(5px);
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}

.content:hover .hide {
  animation-name: anim;
  animation-duration: 700ms;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(5px);
    opacity: 1;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="b1">hover</div>
  <div class="hide">Text</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="b1">hover</div>
  <div class="hide">Text</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="b1">hover</div>
  <div class="hide">Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Это внесите в css

```
.content:hover .hide {
  display: inline-block;
}
```